# non-rectangular hoverable area

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, css-shapes

I would like to have an arrow which will do something on `:hover` but only when the arrow itself is hovered (not the rectangle which delimits its width and height).

In short, when you hover on the right-bottom and right-top corners of an ► it shouldn't do anything.

How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 6):

With a HTML map element? See [< map >](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/map).

**Update:**

For example, like in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PUqCz/):

```css
img {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<br />
<img id="img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3c/Black_triangle.svg/200px-Black_triangle.svg.png" usemap="#triangle" alt="" />
<map name="triangle">
    <area shape="poly" coords="3, 3, 195, 3, 100, 169"
        href="http://google.com" alt=""
        onmouseover="document.getElementById('img').style.borderColor = 'red';"
        onmouseout="document.getElementById('img').style.borderColor = 'black';"/>
</map>
```

Comment: So where should I put the `onmouseover`?

Comment: Another thing could you confirm that `area:hover` won't have any effect?

Comment: @Knu Yes I can confirm for IE7, IE8, IE9, Opera 11.50, Safari 5.0.5, FF 5.0, Chrome 12.0, all on Win7x64, but only from my own observations. Finding a reference of area:hover in the W3C documentation isn't easy.

Answer (score 5):

Iff you have time -- learn SVG in JavaScript -- then, things like these will be nothing more than child's play.

Some useful links for SVG...

http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/

[this tutorial](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CE0QFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fsvg%2Fdefault.asp&ei=uk4hTqW-NMnhrAfr6Ij8AQ&usg=AFQjCNGIXbrp_CrRDePcngdErYdlhAf-PQ)

http://raphaeljs.com/ (my favourite)

http://keith-wood.name/svg.html

Comment: Iv heard of Raphaël before, Ill probably opt for a lighter solution though.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use oldschool [imagemaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/map) or track mousemovement throught the [mousemove event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onmousemove) and then do x/y coordinate calculations.